# '[<InstructionContentViewController] this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key instructionImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, pageviews

I have a slight problem with my code. I keep getting the following message appear when I try to I have two page view controllers in my application. Both are being used for different things. I copied and pasted my coding for the first page controller I implemented and then I changed around the names to prevent conflicts. I recently started to recieve this error message and now my program can no longer work. Can anyone please tell me why this happens?

I also get an error which says method 'pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:' in protocol not implemented. Im not too sure if this is a linked problem, but does anyone know why I get this?

```
#import "StorageViewController.h"
#import "InstructionContentViewController.h"

@interface StorageViewController ()

@end

@implementation StorageViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Create the data model
        _pageInstructTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];
        _pageInstructImages = @[@"instructions1.png", @"instructions2.png", @"instructions3.png", @"instructions4.png"];

        // Create page view controller
        self.instructViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InstructionViewController"];
        self.instructViewController.dataSource = self;

        InstructionContentViewController *startingInstructViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *viewInstructControllers = @[startingInstructViewController];
        [self.instructViewController setViewControllers:viewInstructControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

        // Change the size of page view controller
        self.instructViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

        [self addChildViewController:_instructViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:_instructViewController.view];
        [self.instructViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)startInstructWalkthrough:(id)sender {

    InstructionContentViewController *startingInstructViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingInstructViewController];
    [self.instructViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
}


#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source Methods:

- (UIViewController *)instructViewController:(UIPageViewController *)instructViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewInstructController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((InstructionContentViewController*) viewInstructController).instructPageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}


- (UIViewController *)instructViewController:(UIPageViewController *)instructViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewInstructController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((InstructionContentViewController*) viewInstructController).instructPageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageInstructTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (InstructionContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageInstructTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageInstructTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    InstructionContentViewController *instructionContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InstructionContentViewController"];
    instructionContentViewController.instructImageFile = self.pageInstructImages[index];
    instructionContentViewController.instructTitleText = self.pageInstructTitles[index];
    instructionContentViewController.instructPageIndex = index;

    return instructionContentViewController;


}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)instructViewController
{
    return [self.pageInstructTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)instructViewController
{
    return 0;
}



@end
```

Comment: Looks like you might be using interface builder files for the two classes. If that's the case, did you copy content from one interface builder file to the other? If so, you should have a look at the connections tab in the second class for "instructionImageView", I've had the same exception before due to this, as you'll have removed/renamed the IBOutlet but the interface builder file will be looking for the one by the name of "instructionImageView"

Comment: @mMo That was a small part of the problem but i still get an error which says method 'pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:' in protocol not implemented. Would you happen to know why i get this message?

Comment: That problem warrants another, separate question, but that would be because you haven't implemented the pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController: method, which is part of the protocol the class conforms to. To fix this you would need to add the method to your .m file, and of course add whatever functionality you would need to in that method.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation here for help on how to implement that method if you need it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerDataSourceProtocolRef/UIPageViewControllerDataSource.html